# How to capture data flow component name dynamically while package SSIS package is executing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I would like to fetch the data flow component name while package is executing. Since system variable named [System::SourceName] only fetches name of the control flow tasks?
Is there a way to capture them using script component?

I want to log the data flow task component and would like to keep record of how many rows have been affected during the package run. I know Row Count gives the number of row being processed but also have to capture the name of the data flow task component. I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Could you help me understand what you are attempting to accomplish? Perhaps a diagram of a data flow + what you expect/desire to get from it. Are you targeting a SQL Server 2012+ or pre-2012/2012 with project deployment model?

Comment: I want to log the data flow task component and would like to keep record of how many rows have been affected during the package run. I know Row Count gives the number of row being processed but also have to capture the name of the data flow task component. I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: I think you want system.sourcename.  I use that all over the place in my custom logging.  Although for my row count logging, I use the table name.

Answer (score 0):

I would enable the built-in Logging feature, and direct the output to the msdb database. Then I would query the sysssislog table.

Then I would enjoy a peaceful cup of tea while I contemplated how much time had I saved vs reinventing the wheel with a custom solution.  I might even stare out the window for a while ...

Comment: While I enjoy a nice cup of tea (and looking out the window!), I find the built in logging to be lacking. For example, unless something has changed, the built in logging doesn't capture row counts, which is what the OP is looking to do.

Comment: You might need to log OnProgress and/or OnPipelinerowssent messages.  You can also use a Script component with Dts.Events.FireInformation to write out your own message e.g. based on a RowCount.